# SessionNotCreatedException in Eclipse "Appium" code

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, appium

My Code to execute a simple click button automation is given below , I am very new to appium so I am just trying to get my app and click one button , as i have given my exception down it is stopping me to proceed

```
public class IOSTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver;
     DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
     capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "iOS");
     capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "8.1");
     capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","iPadAir Simulator");
     capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/AZ-Admin/Documents/test.app");
     driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

     if(driver!=null)
     {
         driver.quit();
 }

     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAButton[1]")).click();
 }
 }
```

I Got the below exception when the compiler reached "`driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);`" , can anyone help me

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Requested a new session but one was in progress) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.19 seconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
System info: host: 'CodeWarrior.local', ip: '192.168.0.114', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.1', java.version: '1.7.0_71'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:153)
    at CalculatorTest.IOSTester.main(IOSTester.java:28)
```

Thank you

Comment: "Original error: Requested a new session but one was in progress"

so there is already a session that is created for that device and that is not over.

Comment: so do i need to close my xcode simulator ? And then try

Comment: Yes you should try that out first. Restart your appium server and simulator and run the code.

Comment: I tried it remains the same , so I tried editing my URL and got a new exception , i.e., Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: That URL did not map to a valid JSONWP resource
Command duration or timeout: 230 milliseconds

Comment: Is there any General Settings in appium server which I may be missing in this case ?

Comment: your desired capability browser is ios . Shouldnt it be safari ? 
From the appium docs > 
browserName--Name of mobile web browser to automate. Should be an empty string if automating an app instead. ‘Safari’ for iOS and ‘Chrome’, ‘Chromium’, or ‘Browser’ for Android

Comment: I want to run it in simulator not on browser so i have given ios and version 8.1 and specified device as Ipad Air

Comment: @ Shamik thanks for your help finally got a solution and have posted it as answer

Comment: @user3724559, make sure that u r Appium is running.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to

```
public class IOSTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    AppiumDriver driver;
     DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
     capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "iOS");
     capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "8.1");
     capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
     capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","iPad Air");
     capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/AZ-Admin/Documents/test.app");
     driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAButton[1]")).click();
 }
 }
```

Download Appium Driver.jar and attach it to your code file and Import AppiumDriver